# Problema con Bucle MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedure

Buenas tengo un procedimiento en SQL varios bucles con WHILE que lo que hace es sacarme una pirámide con el numero de entrada que le introduzca.
La cuestion que ahora necesito que la piramide se me muestre con el mismo numero, es decir si introducimos 4 la piramide debera mostrar:

```
 4444
  444
   44
    4
```

Y no

```
 4444
  333
   22
    1
```

Pero por mas vueltas que le doy no consigo encontrar el 'error'

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS P06_PIRAMIDE_INVERSA;

DELIMITER |

CREATE PROCEDURE P06_PIRAMIDE_INVERSA(IN numero INTEGER, OUT mensaje TEXT)

BEGIN

     DECLARE caracteres INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
     DECLARE espacios INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
     DECLARE filas INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

     SET mensaje = 'La pirámide inversa del número ';
     SET mensaje = CONCAT(mensaje,numero,' es:\n\n');

     IF numero > 0 AND numero < 10 THEN
          WHILE numero > 0 DO
               SET espacios = numero - (numero - filas);
                    WHILE espacios > 0 DO
                         SET mensaje = CONCAT(mensaje,' ');    
                         SET espacios = espacios - 1;
                    END WHILE;
                         SET caracteres = numero;
                    WHILE caracteres > 0 DO
                         SET mensaje = CONCAT(mensaje,numero);
                         SET caracteres = caracteres - 1;
                    END WHILE;
               SET numero = numero - 1;
               SET filas = filas + 1;
               SET mensaje = CONCAT(mensaje,'\n');
          END WHILE;
     ELSE
          SET mensaje = 'ERROR!! Introduzca un numero del 1 al 9';
     END IF;

END |

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás rellenando con `numero` que, a la vez, estás decrementando. Créate una variable `relleno` con un valor fijo y lo resolverás:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE P06_PIRAMIDE_INVERSA(IN numero INTEGER, OUT mensaje TEXT)
BEGIN
     DECLARE caracteres INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
     DECLARE espacios INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
     DECLARE filas INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
     DECLARE relleno INT;

     SET mensaje = 'La pirámide inversa del número ';
     SET mensaje = CONCAT(mensaje,numero,' es:\n\n');
     SET relleno = numero;

     IF numero > 0 AND numero < 10 THEN
          WHILE numero > 0 DO
               SET espacios = numero - (numero - filas);
                    WHILE espacios > 0 DO
                         SET mensaje = CONCAT(mensaje,' ');    
                         SET espacios = espacios - 1;
                    END WHILE;
                         SET caracteres = numero;
                    WHILE caracteres > 0 DO
                         SET mensaje = CONCAT(mensaje,relleno);
                         SET caracteres = caracteres - 1;
                    END WHILE;
               SET numero = numero - 1;
               SET filas = filas + 1;
               SET mensaje = CONCAT(mensaje,'\n');
          END WHILE;
     ELSE
          SET mensaje = 'ERROR!! Introduzca un numero del 1 al 9';
     END IF;
END
```